# Recover displayed JSON data from webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a webpage on JSFiddle that can display a simple JSON string. I plan on implementing ways to add/edit/remove keys and values, which is what the buttons on the right are for. Before adding all that, how do I go from this webpage representation back to a JSON string with the same formating when I click 'Save'?

Do I need to tag each element specifically some how and do a forEach(element) and extract the text value and then..?

Code on  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HTMLforTasker/sg3ej2fp/37/)

```
<script>
var new_json = {"RegEx":{}}
var keys = document.getElementsByClassName("json_header")

for (key in keys){

  //Somehow extract key value that is displayed, add to new_json as a key.

  // for each key, need to add each value.
  for (value in values){?}
}
```

Somehow I need to know which values belong to which key, is this possible with parent/child associaton?
In the JSFiddle, I append all the values as children to the key value

New to HTML and Javascript, any other suggestions are welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: Keep the original data, perform adding/changing directly on that, and update the DOM based on the data. Also take a look at https://vuejs.org/

Comment: I don't really get what you want to do in the question. It is kind of confusing. Do you want to use a base json and write some other json over it?

Comment: Do not think it is a good task for a newbie - maybe you should find ready made editor, parser, etc., but in case there are objects holding info of each item, postion to text and size in source code in abc notation web editor, which have way more complicated content.

Comment: @ariel Thanks! That sounds like a great idea. How do I address the specific key / value on button click?

Comment: @PrikeshSavla I have the JSON and I need a means of adding/editing/removing keys and values from the input JSON.

Comment: @Tom It's for a mini program thing on my phone, I'm looking for a means to edit my JSON on my phone instead of extracting it and editing it on my computer.

Comment: In case you do not have to care about its validity or it is not too big, there is a bunch of general text editors then ??

Comment: @Tom, it's for a budgeting program. The data passed to it is somewhat sensitive and I need a way for me to edit any parameters which are stored in JSON. I want an easy way to do so as I don't like having to go into the program, copy out the JSON to make the changes. So I'm looking for a more user friendly approach.


This project is on my android phone using an app called Tasker. The JSON created by notifications from my phone which Tasker takes, parses, and stores as part of the JSON. I just need a way to make some changes to a few parts of the JSON and needed a UI to do so.

Comment: In case they are not too complicated, I would use fixed or dynamic form to edit these parts. Fully generic editor could be a (bad) reinvented wheel :-)

Comment: then the idea @ariel gave is really relevant here. You can use that. So eventually you have a input json and want to edit it and get a json back? is this your example json?  `var input_json = '{"RegEx":{"key1":["item1","item2"],"key2":["item3"],"key3":["item4"],"key4":["item5"]}}'`

Comment: @PrikeshSavla, yes input_json is an example of the format I will be using. There may be more keys, each key will have a varying number of 'items', but it will have the same format.

If I am to follow the idea ariel gave, how do I update the json stemming from a button click next to that item?

Comment: If this is not a learning task, you might benefit from the wonderful http://jsoneditoronline.org/ website. The source code is also fully available as a Github project: https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor

Comment: do you want to do it with an interface correct? if you use vue js it might add a learning curve to figure it out? do you wanna do that. i can give you an example. what do you say?

Comment: @PrikeshSavla Yes, with an interface, I've updated the JSFiddle link in the OP, didn't realise the fiddle was broken before, that's kind of what I was going for and then having buttons on the side to give the option to add/edit/delete. I'll hapilly take an example, thank you very much.

Comment: @PrikeshSavla I think I'm onto something and may not need the example. ariel's idea got me thinking and I went back to one of my original sources of inspiration for this. It gives back the key[item] pair on click of the button. So I'm moulding it to suit my needs at the moment.